# 8086 assembly language

Tags: x86-16

what is the significance of

```
mov ax,@data
```

Why do we write it?

Answer (score 1):

Usually that line would be followed by:

```
mov ds,ax
```

E.g.:

```
mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
```

...which sets the `ds` (data segment) register to point to the [data segment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_segment) created by the program launcher.

I'm not having much luck finding a good link for you other than the WP link above (my search-fu must be weak this morning), but basically, the x86 memory architecture is a *segmented* architecture, where different segments can be defined as having separate purposes (code, data, statically-initialized data, etc.). The processor then does some useful things for us, like preventing our executing data rather than code.

Comment: thnx. well i have tons of question in 8086 programming. It would very kind of you to help me. are u available for chat.

Comment: @user: I'm a weak reed to lean on for 8086 programming, I'm afraid. I haven't done any for 15 years. Check the profiles of the [top 8086 users](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/8086/topusers) on the site, if any of them are happy to be contacted, their profiles should say. Best,